# InnoDB cluster memory issue with LOAD DATA

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile, mysql-innodb-cluster

I need to create a new table with ~8M rows without causing too much noise for other services using the cluster. I split the data into chunks of 100k rows and use `LOAD DATA LOCAL FILE`, sleep 5s and repeat. Mysql starts to consume all memory until OOM kills mysqld on the cluster nodes.

*What am I doing wrong??*

Any help or ideas on how to progress are welcome, thanks!

InnoDB Cluster 8.0.24, Ubuntu 20.04 on three virtual hosts (same behavior for 8.0.23). 6 CPU cores, 12GB memory each. The only configuration change from default is `local_infile = ON`.

Additional info as kindly requested by @Wilson (links to pastebin):

1. [Primary, with no memory issue](https://pastebin.com/3xhi5SS0)
2. [Secondary, with memory issue](https://pastebin.com/3djU6XCs)

My table I'm loading data into:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `RefdataSnapshotM_20210421140303` (
  `SERVICE_INFO`             VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
  `PORTING_TIME`             TIMESTAMP   DEFAULT NULL,
  `IDN`                      VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
  `PORTING_ID`               VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
  `RECIPIENT_SP_ID`          CHAR(3)     NOT NULL,
  `DONOR_SP_ID`              CHAR(3)     NOT NULL,
  `RECIPIENT_ROUTING_NUMBER` CHAR(3)     NOT NULL,
  `DONOR_ROUTING_NUMBER`     CHAR(3)     NOT NULL,
  `PORTING_INDICATOR`        VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
  `CREATION_DATE`            TIMESTAMP   DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`IDN`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

How I load data:

```
LOAD DATA
  LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/datasource.dat'
  INTO TABLE `RefdataSnapshotM_20210421140303`
  CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
  (
    `SERVICE_INFO`,
    @var_PORTING_TIME,
    @var_IDN,
    `PORTING_ID`,
    `RECIPIENT_SP_ID`,
    `DONOR_SP_ID`,
    `RECIPIENT_ROUTING_NUMBER`,
    `DONOR_ROUTING_NUMBER`,
    `PORTING_INDICATOR`,
    @var_CREATION_DATE
  )
  SET  `PORTING_TIME` = STR_TO_DATE(@var_PORTING_TIME, GET_FORMAT(DATETIME, 'INTERNAL')),
                `IDN` = REGEXP_REPLACE(@var_IDN, '^46', '', 1),
      `CREATION_DATE` = STR_TO_DATE(@var_CREATION_DATE, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s')
```

Some memory related info:

```
SELECT total_allocated DIV total_allocated 1024 AS FROM sys.x$memory_global_total
+-----------------+
| total_allocated |
+-----------------+
| 11366374 kB     |
+-----------------+
cat /proc/<pid_of_mysql_here>/smaps_rollup
Rss:            11784296 kB
Pss:            11783545 kB
Pss_Anon:       11767256 kB
Pss_File:          16289 kB
Pss_Shmem:             0 kB
Shared_Clean:        952 kB
Shared_Dirty:          0 kB
Private_Clean:     16196 kB
Private_Dirty:  11767148 kB
Referenced:     11123016 kB
Anonymous:      11767256 kB
LazyFree:              0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
FilePmdMapped:         0 kB
Shared_Hugetlb:        0 kB
Private_Hugetlb:       0 kB
Swap:             371376 kB
SwapPss:          371376 kB
Locked:                0 kB

SELECT SUM(current_alloc) AS total_allocated
  FROM sys.x$memory_global_by_current_bytes
UNION
SELECT total_allocated
  FROM sys.x$memory_global_total;
+-----------------+
| total_allocated |
+-----------------+
|      1344314202 |
|      1344251938 |
+-----------------+
```

Comment: Additional information request from any single cluster
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes -
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Thank for this input! I've updated the question with a link to much more information. Next time the system is about to die on me I'll dump the same info again here in hope it'll bring some more light n the issue.

Comment: I've also updated with more info from a node when it's about to run out of memory.

Comment: Analysis in process.  Hope to have suggestions posted in less than 24 hours.

Comment: Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server?

Comment: Unfortunately not, and according to the sysadmins it wasn't even possible to install one. I know virtual cluster nodes is not recommended. But that's what I've to deal with :/

Comment: Many people are still running fine on rotating drives.  How old is your CPU - appx year of manufacture?

Comment: The CPU is from Q1'16: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 v4 @ 2.10GHz

Answer (score 0):

Rate Per Second = RPS

Suggestions to consider for avoiding OOM on your Secondary instance,

HTOP additional discussion to achieve Sleeping tasks reduction

Show Full Process list indicates event_scheduler is 'ON' and appears to always be idle.
Please post results of SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'com%event%'; for confirmation.

ulimit -a report indicates Open Files limited to 1024 and yet MySQL instance is asking for open_files_limit of 10,000.  Additional discussion needed.

In your SECONDARY my.cnf [mysqld] section, consider these possible values to improve performance,

```
read_rnd_buffer_size=128K  # from 256K to reduce handler_read_rnd_next RPS of 139
max_connections=64  # from default of 151 since max_used_connections was 19 in 2+ days
innodb_lru_scan_depth=100  # from 1024 to conserve 90% of cpu cycles used for function
innodb_log_buffer_size=96M  # from 16M for ~ 30 minutes bufffering before write to log
innodb_change_buffer_max_size=50  # from 25 (percent) to reduce time required to LOAD data to tables
innodb_concurrency_tickets=20000  # from 5000 to reduce reque by extending time allowed for inserts
```

This is just the beginning of improving your response time and throughput of data.

Comment: Thank you Wilson! <3 I'll run through your findings tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks, have a GREAT evening.

Comment: We've tested all combinations of your suggested changes but with little to no success. Some of them seem to be performance oriented, that's nice, but our concern is that the nodes dies due to too much memory consumption. I'm greatful for your input though!

Comment: @MyGGaN It would take all the suggestions applied to cumulatively improve performance.  If you need additional suggestions we have a profile.